# MSAL SDK with ROPC authentication flow combined with certificate assertion - is possible

Tags: azure-active-directory, x509certificate, azure-ad-msal

I'm working with a client where we need to use the ROPC authentication process together with a certificate assertion (instead of client secret). I now this flow is not recommended but it's currently the selected option. It's a C# deamon application we are talking about.

I have been able to do this by getting a client assertion token using the certificate and using username and password, replacing the client_secret key with client_assertion using a regular http rest call. However I would obviously much rather user the MSAL SDK to avoid all plumming that rest calls lead you to.  Has anybody done this, do you know if this scenario is supported using the MSAL SDK? I couldn't find anything about it...

[This is the ROPC standard call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0h16.png)

...that I have replaced with
[the following (first getting the client assertion with a certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNrr4.png)

Answer (score 1):

At present,The Microsoft Authentication Library ([MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows)) supports several authentication flows for use in different application scenarios.
If your application is daemon type, it applies only to the client credential flow and cannot be used for the ROPC flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was my conclusion also - this was just to verify since it is supported by doing REST calls as my image shows (even though not recommended, although there is a reason for using it my scenario)